# Destiny Nightfall with 2 players, one dead, did we time out or did I run too far away?

Tags: destiny

We're quite the newbies when it comes to nightfall strikes in Destiny but we tried nevertheless.

It was the Nexus strike and we got so far as to get into the cavern hallway above the last boss.

While trying to get rid of the minotaurs down in the area below (where the main/last boss will spawn when we've taken care of the stragglers), the "anti-camp minotaur" spawned in the hallway behind us and managed to kill my partner.

I ran back up past him and managed to get back out of the cavern. We tried different attacks but I was unable to take down his shield. I ran out of special ammo and decided to run back to a previous area in order to see if ammo boxes was still lying around, waiting for my replenishment items to cool down.

While running through the caverns before this, the game ended us, kicking us back to orbit, as though we had both died.

My question is this: Why did this happen?

1. Was it because my partner was dead too long?
2. Was it because I ran too far away from my partner while he was dead?
3. Was it some other limitation other than the two above that I cannot see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From experience if some of the party are in a darkness zone and some are not, if the people in the darkness zone die it counts as a wipe. In a normal instance this means everybody respawns at the start of the darkness zone - an interesting experience if in a strike and some people are running ahead past all the optional encounters and die in the darkness zone those hanging behind in the optional encounters get teleported up.

In a nightfall strike of course this would mean it counts as a party wipe and thus boots you back to orbit.

So the answer to point 1 is no, it doesn't matter how long your partner has been dead. The answer is point 2 pretty much - you ran far enough away to be out of the darkness zone. 3 is pretty much Not applicable therefore. :)